# UINavigationItem modal how to inherit color from presentingviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I have a modal view controller, and I want its navigation bar (I think UINavigationItem) to inherit the color of the navigation bar of its presenting view controller.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup it before presenting modal view controller. For example:

```
viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```